# How to create a correlation matrix with correlations from one df below the diagonal and from another df above the diagonal?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two data sets (i.e. different data frames) containing the same set of variables (measured at two different time points). I would like to create a correlation matrix (all variables correlated with each other) separately for both data sets. I would like to report them in one table showing the correlations from data set 1 below the diagonal and from data set 2 above the diagonal. Is there a special R function that will lead me to this goal (preferably in a way that I can export the full correlation matrix as Excel)?

Many thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

This correlation matrix sounds rather bespoke, but here's a method you can adapt.

```r
corr2 <- function(x, y) {
  cor1 <- cor(x)
  cor2 <- cor(y)
  cor1[upper.tri(cor1)] <- cor2[upper.tri(cor2)]
  cor1
}
mtsplit <- lapply(split(mtcars[,1:4], seq_len(nrow(mtcars)) %% 2), head, 10)
corr2(mtsplit[[1]], mtsplit[[2]])
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.8349547 -0.8733379 -0.8880032
# cyl  -0.9015514  1.0000000  0.8980527  0.9160083
# disp -0.8945514  0.8481032  1.0000000  0.9266008
# hp   -0.8793122  0.9683139  0.8962127  1.0000000
```

If we debug that function and look at each value, we see:

```r
cor1
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.9015514 -0.8945514 -0.8793122
# cyl  -0.9015514  1.0000000  0.8481032  0.9683139
# disp -0.8945514  0.8481032  1.0000000  0.8962127
# hp   -0.8793122  0.9683139  0.8962127  1.0000000
cor2
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.8349547 -0.8733379 -0.8880032
# cyl  -0.8349547  1.0000000  0.8980527  0.9160083
# disp -0.8733379  0.8980527  1.0000000  0.9266008
# hp   -0.8880032  0.9160083  0.9266008  1.0000000
```

(And since it's a `matrix`, it can be written to a CSV file with `write.csv`, i.e., Excel-friendly.)